# Combine an absolute path with a relative path

Tags: c#, path

Let's say I have defined an absolute path

```
string abs = "X:/A/B/Q";
```

and a relative path

```
string rel = "../B/W";
```

How do I combine these two so that it results in following output?

```
"X:/A/B/W"
```

I already tried `Path.Combine()`, but not successfully.

Comment: Don't you miss one `..`? If `rel = "../../B/W"` it will be valid. Instead it will be `X:/A/B/B/W`

Comment: What you want is wrong, and wudzik was right. If you are in the Q folder, .. will bring you to the B folder, so you'll have X:/A/B/B/W .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
string abs = "X:/A/B/Q";
string rel = "../../B/W";
var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(abs,rel));
```

It will give you full absolute path
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx

Comment: This prints `X:/A/B/Q\../B/W`

Comment: @SonerGönül I checked it and it should return this, because there is missing one `..`, it can't return one `B` less.

Answer (score 0):

I improve the above code from @wudzik

```
public static string ConvertRelativePathToAbsolutePath(string basePath, string path)
{
    if (System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(basePath) == true || System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) == true) return "";
    //Gets a value indicating whether the specified path string contains a root.
    //This method does not verify that the path or file name exists.
    if (System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(path) == true)
    {
        return path;
    }
    else
    {
        return System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(basePath, path));
    }
}
```