# Haskell: how calculate absolute path from an absolute path and a relative path pair

Tags: haskell, filepath

I need to achieve the same as the following C# code in Haskell:

```
string abs = "X:/A/B/Q";
string rel = "../../B/W";
var path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(abs,rel));

=> "X:/A/B/W"
```

ref: [Combine an absolute path with a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443877/combine-an-absolute-path-with-a-relative-path)

Is there any standard package out there that can do this?

Hoogling found me makeAbsolute and canonicalizePath but they both use the current directory as the base not a provided file path.

I am guessing any Haskell version would need to return something like IO (Either String FilePath)

Comment: Have you looked at [`System.IO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#t:FilePath)?

Comment: Nothing I can see there looks like it solves the problem

Comment: Then [`System.FilePath.Posix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.1.2/docs/System-FilePath-Posix.html#v:normalise) and [`System.Directory`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.2.2/docs/System-Directory.html) have all you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can combine paths with [(</>)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath-1.4.1.2/docs/System-FilePath-Posix.html#v:-60--47--62-):

```
abs </> rel
```

then use `canonicalizePath` to remove any indirection.

```
canonicalizePath (abs </> rel) >>= \abs -> ...
```